# Git corrupted objects after swap creation

Tags: git, composer-php

`[RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone git@github.com:fzaninotto/Faker.git via git, https, ssh protocols, aborting.
  - git://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker.git
    warning: expected SRV RR, found RR type 1
    error: inflate: data stream error (invalid code lengths set)
    error: failed to read object a57966bf6d6c097874c0bf872d21aae15c8f28f3 at offset 87642 from .git/objects/
  pack/pack-af626bfbb17429c4050c9dd60b32da7545b3c682.pack
    fatal: packed object a57966bf6d6c097874c0bf872d21aae15c8f28f3 (stored in .git/objects/pack/pack-af626bfb
  b17429c4050c9dd60b32da7545b3c682.pack) is corrupt
    fatal: write error: Broken pipe
    fatal: index-pack failed
  - https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker.git
    error: inflate: data stream error (invalid code lengths set)
    error: failed to read object a57966bf6d6c097874c0bf872d21aae15c8f28f3 at offset 87642 from .git/objects/
  pack/pack-af626bfbb17429c4050c9dd60b32da7545b3c682.pack
    fatal: packed object a57966bf6d6c097874c0bf872d21aae15c8f28f3 (stored in .git/objects/pack/pack-af626bfb
  b17429c4050c9dd60b32da7545b3c682.pack) is corrupt
    error: fetch-pack died of signal 13
  - git@github.com:fzaninotto/Faker.git
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

It appeared after I created a new swap file (Ubuntu). 
How to fix the problem?
That's how I did it - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

`vagrant@precise64:/dev$ sudo swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/mapper/precise64-swap_1            partition       786428  0       -1
/swapfile                               file            4194300 0       -2`

It seems that the one that have 786428  size was my previous swap file. Does objects I need are probably there?..

Comment: Please paste the error text into your question - we try to avoid web links (pastebin etc,) as they eventually expire and then the question is no longer useful to others.

Comment: Did you do it using `dd`, or with `fallocate`?

Comment: I did it using ```fallocate```.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?..

Comment: I do not, but some others might.  I wanted to help you improve the question to attract more answers. Good you posted the extra info. I presume you already tried Google for othera with similar problems?

Comment: Yes, I tried of course. I have no ideas what to do. Now I try to create a new vagrant virtual environment as I need to develop my project... But that is not the best solution...